# algorithm to return a sting as follows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have to write a function that take `A`,`B` as integers and have to return string contains exactly A letters of `Y` B letters of `N` with no 3 consecutive letters being the same.

Comment: What have _you_ tried to implement this?

Comment: this sounds like homewoke so a little hint // divides and rounds down % shows what is left

Comment: @niteeshk you'r not able to think about it ?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it effectively

Comment: Assume `A>=B`, otherwise reverse `A` and `B`. Also assume `(A-B)<3`, else it can't be done. Output `B` instances of `ab` followed by `A-B` instances of `a`. Hopefully you can code this in python.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle That's not correct. aabaabaabaa has 8 times a and 3 times b.

Comment: can you guys help me now to solve it with efficiency?

Comment: hello there?? can you suggest me a better way to o it??

Comment: @Henry Not sure where `aabaabaabaa` comes from? My suggestion generates `abababaa`

Comment: send me the code ?

Comment: @niteeshk With your posted code you're over-complicating things. Have you tried coding up my suggestion?

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle it is a valid solution for A=8 B=3 with A-B=5

Comment: no I just wrote this way and I didnt check , can u help me or just I will keep calm.. I am getting runtime error

Comment: @Henry Of course, thanks. Output should be `('a'*(A/B) + 'b')*B + 'a'*(A-B*(A/B))`, where `A>=B, B>0, A/B<3`

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle actually, the condition for the existence of a solution in the case A>B is A<=2*B+2. Otherwise you get too many a at the end. Also if A/B<2 you would get all remaining a at the end.

Comment: for anyone who is finding the solution, here is a similar answer in javascript for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905491/4810199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is obviously a homework question, I will just give some hints.

First, not all parameter combinations do have a solution, for example A=3, B=0.

Can you think of a working strategy when A=B?

Now assume A > B. What can you output to bring the numbers of remaining characters closer together? So that eventually they are the same.

Comment: My answer still is the same after the update of the question. It sketches an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this page when I have to take the similar homework as @niteesh k

My answer is inspired by the comments here and also the solution given using java script.
I thought it would be useful for those who are still looking for a solution in python

```
def sol(A, B):

    if abs(A-B)>3:
        print('Desired Solution is impossible')

    else:
        d = {'a': A, 'b': B}
        full_str = ''
        length = A + B                                 

        next_chr = 'a' if A >= B else 'b'             

        for i in range(length):
            full_str += next_chr             
            d[next_chr] -= 1                

            if len(full_str) > 1:                        
                if (full_str[-1] == next_chr and full_str[-2] == next_chr) or (d[next_chr] == 0):
                    if next_chr == 'a': 
                        next_chr = 'b'
                    else: 
                        next_chr = 'a'

        print(full_str)
```

Comment: this is wrong , check with sol(4,7) , your code fails.